# How can I add a group as a member of another group on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

AWS IAM easily allows to add users to groups.

How can I add a group to another group, so that all permissions are 'nested', or 'inherited'?

I want to avoid having to add users multiple times, or attaching permission multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have nested groups, as mentioned in the [AWS IAM user groups Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups.html):

> - A user group can contain many users, and a user can belong to multiple user groups.
> - User groups can't be nested; they can contain only users, not other user groups.

However, you can attach an IAM Policy (service permission) across multiple groups and/or users giving permissions in a nested way.